# wysiwyg missing on Campaign description

Tags: civicampaign, wysiwyg

Strangely, We have a wysiwyg for the campaigns goal field on New/Edit Campaign form but not description field. Is that intentional? Our users are not high tech and are not familiar with HTML tags. Is it an easy thing to enable on description field?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should have the wysiwyg on campaign description field after installing [Convert textare to WYSIWYG extension](https://github.com/pradpnayak/texttockeditor/blob/master/texttockeditor.php)

HTH

Pradeep

Comment: Unfortunately the extension isn't in the list inside your CiviCRM install. And many folks will only install those on the extensions page.

Comment: Agreed, There are lots of extensions which sits on their individual/Organization git/gitlab/bitbucket account because they were never meant to release under Civi Extension. If there is a request to have this available as part of Civi Extension I am happy to do that. Its users choice if they want to use extension from Civi extension page and/or from other repos

Comment: Yes, it's best to do it that way, as then people are more comfortable with it. Plus it makes it easier for folks to install.